# Combine related data with promise results

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an array of objects that I need to make an async call
for each one, once all calls have been made I'd like to package each module up as an object containing the original object's detail, and the
new results from the async call, and put that all in an array.

Im having some trouble trying to figure how to combine the original module object with the async
result.

This is what I have so far -

```
const modules = [{name: 'module1', id: 1}, {name: 'module2', id: 2}, ..etc];

let modulesHistory = []; // my final array object
let modulesPromises = []; // store all my promises

modules.forEach((module) => {
  const buildHistory = new BuildHistory(module.id); // my collection

  // I tried to do something like this
  // but it's not really doing it:
  // 
  // modulesHistory.push({
  //   module: module, 
  //   builds: buildHistory 
  // });

  modulesPromises.push(buildHistory.fetch()); // fetch returns a promise

});

$.when.apply($, modulesPromises).done(function(){
  // Afterwards I'd like modulesHistory to look like: 
  // [
  //   {
  //     module: {
  //       name: 'module1',
  //       id: 1
  //     },
  //     data: {
  //       // stuff returned from asyc
  //     }
  //   },
  //   {
  //     module: {
  //       name: 'module2',
  //       id: 2
  //     },
  //     data: {
  //       // stuff returned from asyc
  //     }
  //   }
  // ]

  doStuff(modulesHistory);
});
```

Comment: You seem to be using ES6 - why don't you use native promises?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Augment the result of a call to `buildHistory#fetch` by wrapping it in a `new Promise` and manually resolving to an object that takes the current `module` and the `data` returned from `buildHistory#fetch`:

```
let modulesPromises = modules.map(module => {
    const buildHistory = new BuildHistory(module.id)
    return new Promise(res => buildHistory.fetch().then(data => res({module, data}))
})
```

Or, as @torazaburo suggests, we can compact this functionality further by avoiding creating a `new Promise`:

```
let modulesPromises = modules.map(module => {
    return new BuildHistory(module.id)
        .fetch()
        .then(data => ({module, data}))
})
```

Indeed, as @Bergi has mentioned in a comment, you should consider using the native implementation of Promises (that is available in ES6) to access the final result:

```
Promise.all(modulePromises).then(res => {
    // res is an array of the result of each Promise in `modulePromises`
})
```